# Override making error in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have been trying to make an app which uses Firebase Push notification,But an getting this error in Myfirebasemessaginservie class which is "Method does not override method from super class" :

```
package com.flymit.firebasenotificationexam;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    private static final String Tag="MyFirebasemsgservice";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(){

    }
}
```

Help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `message` parameter. Method declaration should look like `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)`.

Answer (score 0):

check once you have added in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'

}
```

you missed parameters in that method .so change your method like this

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.i("TAG", "MESSAGE RECEIVED!!");

}
```

Comment: Got it Thanks @sasikumar :)